# p:selectBooleanButton DENTRO DE p:tab JSF PRIMFACES (me da error, no me sale la acción de pulsar el botón)

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo el siguiente codigo metido dentro de un p:tab, el caso es que si lo saco del p:tab si me funciona pero dentro de el no. Llevo bastante rato y no consigo nada.

```
                            <div class="row col-sm-12 text-center"
                                style="display: flex; margin: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="TX:" styleClass="col-sm-3" />
                                    <p:selectBooleanButton id="value2"
                                        style="background: #2f5879;color: #fff !important;"
                                        value="#{channelControlBean.select}"
                                        onLabel="MANUAL" offLabel="AUTOMÁTICO" styleClass="col-sm-6">
                                        <p:ajax process="@this" event="change"
                                            listener="#{channelControlBean.change}"
                                            update="form:tabViewChannelControl:transmitButtonLine" />
                                    </p:selectBooleanButton>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="Mensajes en cola TX:"
                                        styleClass="col-sm-6" />
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{channelControlBean.count}"
                                        styleClass="col-sm-6" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arreglado, me estaba dando un problema con la clase **col-sm-12**, no entiendo el porqué, pero haciendo prueba y error quitando código descubrí que era con eso la única forma que fallaba.